# nested array group by value

Tags: node.js, mongodb

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTJBY.png)

data

```
 {
    "id": "1",
    "category": "education",
    "field": "science",
    "items": [
      {
        "title": "item 1",
        "value": "10"
      },
      {
        "title": "item 1",
        "value": "102"
      },
      {
        "title": "item 2",
        "value": "12"
      },
      {
        "title": "item 1",
        "value": "19"
      },
      {
        "title": "item 1",
        "value": "13"
      },
      {
        "title": "item 2",
        "value": "149"
      },
      
    ]
  }
```

i want this with this

```
  {
    "category": "education",
    "field": "science",
    "items": [
      {
        "title": "item 1",
        "value": [
          "10",
          "102",
          "19",  // do not want this    limit : 2
          "13"   //  do not want this    limit : 2
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "item 2",
        "value": [
          "12",
          "149"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you encountering?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the data as you show in _"want this"_, or do you want to update the document in the collection?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want get data using aggregation in mongodb

Answer (score 0):

I think there is probably a more clear/efficient way to do this, but this seems to work.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "items": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$items",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$cond": [
              {"$in": ["$$this.title", "$$value.title"]},
              {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$$value",
                  "as": "elem",
                  "in": {
                    "$cond": [
                      {"$eq": ["$$this.title", "$$elem.title"]},
                      {
                        "title": "$$this.title",
                        "value": {
                          "$firstN": {
                            "n": 2,
                            "input": {"$concatArrays": ["$$elem.value", ["$$this.value"]]}
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "$$elem"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "$concatArrays": [
                  "$$value",
                  [
                    {
                      "title": "$$this.title",
                      "value": ["$$this.value"]
                    }
                  ]
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/S_aRpRn-Yhf).